# Javascript module pattern in D3

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, layout, d3.js, hierarchy

Recently I have been reading about javascript patterns, and how to use module pattern to avoid globals. When I look at d3.js [hierarchy layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/hierarchy.js) source code, I am not sure if the below is intentional.

`d3.layout.hierarchy` is using the module pattern, but towards the end, I see many methods outside of it, which I guess are only applicable to layout and its derived objects (partition, tree..).

```
d3_layout_hierarchyRebind
d3_layout_hierarchyChildren
d3_layout_hierarchyValue
..
```

Is this intentional, or should be captured within the module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the library is built via the [makefile](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/Makefile), these methods are all enclosed within an anonymous function (see [start.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/start.js) and [end.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/end.js)) for the wrapper code. So none of them are global in the final built-out library. This is a design choice to allow the library to be easily split into many files without requiring an anonymous function wrapper for each (as would be the case with [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)-style modules).